# Delphi 2010 : How to emulate the Delphi XE TStrings.Encoding property?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Delphi XE added an `Encoding` property to the `TStrings` class, which stores the encoding read from the BOM when `LoadFromFile()` is called.

Delphi 2010 does not have this property.
 I would like to emulate it.

I created the below class helper for `TStrings`. 
The helper works, but to get the file's BOM, the only solution I have found is to reload the same file in a FileStream.  I would like to avoid this since `TStrings.LoadFromFile()` already got the BOM.

How can I tell the helper to re-use the BOM that was already found?

```
unit TestEncodingName_00;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtDlgs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Memo1: TMemo;
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

TMyStrings = class helper for TStrings   // emulate TStrings.Encoding
private
  function GetEncodingName(fPath:string):string;
public
property EncodingName[fPath:string]:string read GetEncodingName;
end;

var
Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function  TMyStrings.GetEncodingName(fPath:string):string;
var
  fLen : integer;
  fBuffer : TBytes;
  fEncoding : TEncoding;
  fName : string;
  fFs : TFileStream;

begin
   fFs := TFileStream.Create(fPath, fmOpenRead);
 try
    SetLength(fBuffer, 4);
    flen := fFs.Read(fBuffer[0], 4);
    if flen < 4 then
      SetLength(fBuffer, flen);
    fEncoding := nil;
    TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding(fBuffer, fEncoding);
    if fEncoding = TEncoding.Unicode then
    fName := 'Unicode'
  else if fEncoding = TEncoding.UTF8 then
    fName := 'UTF8'
  else fName := 'Default';
  finally
    fFs.Free;
  end;
  result := fName;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  EncName : string;

begin
(* sample UTF8.txt
Ā ā Ă ă
Ρ Σ Τ Υ
ぁ あ ぃ
*)
  Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('Sample UTF8.txt');
  //from here TStrings knows the BOM but I don't know
  // how to refer to it...
  // so I have to create again a stream of the same file to
  // get the BOM. I don't like that.
  EncName :=  Memo1.Lines.EncodingName['Sample UTF8.txt'];
  Memo1.Lines.Add(#13#10'Encoding : ' + EncName);
end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it is `LoadFromStream()` that discovers the BOM encoding, not `LoadFromFile()`. `LoadFromFile()` simply opens the file into a `TFileStream` and then calls `LoadFromStream()`.

In Delphi (2009 and) 2010, the discovered BOM encoding is not stored anywhere that you can access.  That is the very problem that XE solved by adding the new `Encoding` property.  The encoding is only used as a local variable inside of `LoadFromStream()` when decoding the file data to a `UnicodeString` prior to parsing, and then it gets discarded when `LoadFromStream()` exits.  There is nothing you can do to change that behavior.

So, the only solution is to load the file manually so you can discover its BOM.  Ideally, you would override `LoadFromStream()` in a descendant class, but you can't make `TMemo.Lines` use a custom class.  And a `class helper` cannot override virtual methods, either.

However, you can derive a custom class from `TStringList` to override `LoadFromStream()`, load the file yourself, and then `Assign()` the `TStringList` to `TMemo.Lines`.  For example:

```
unit TestEncodingName_00;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtDlgs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TMyStringList = class(TStringList)
  private
    fEncoding: TEncoding;
  public
    { The single-parameter LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream) simply
    calls LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream; Encoding: TEncoding) with
    the Encoding parameter set to nil, so you only have to override
    that version of LoadFromStream()... }
    procedure LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream; Encoding: TEncoding); override;
    property Encoding: TEncoding read fEncoding;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMyStringList.LoadFromStream(Stream: TStream; Encoding: TEncoding);
var
  Size: Integer;
  Buffer: TBytes;
begin
  { this is similar to the implementation that LoadFromStream()
  uses in XE+, but with some differences:

  1. the Encoding property is assigned a bit differently, as XE+
     utilizes a TEncoding.Clone() method when the specified Encoding
     is not a standard RTL encoding (ie, is a custom user class), but
     Clone() does not exist in D2009/2010.

  2. XE+ has a TStrings.DefaultEncoding property, which is passed
     to TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding() as the default to return if no
     BOM is detected, but that property and parameter do not exist in
     D2009/2010.

  3. TStrings.LoadFromStream() does not check if Size is 0 (file is empty)
     before dereferencing the Buffer that is passed to Stream.Read().
     That is a runtime crash waiting to happen! }

  BeginUpdate;
  try
    Size := Stream.Size - Stream.Position;
    SetLength(Buffer, Size);
    if Size > 0 then
      Stream.Read(Buffer[0], Size);
    Size := TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding(Buffer, Encoding);
    fEncoding := Encoding;
    SetTextStr(Encoding.GetString(Buffer, Size, Length(Buffer) - Size));
  finally
    EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  EncName : string;
  List: TMyStringList;
begin
  List := TMyStringList.Create;
  try
    List.LoadFromFile('Sample UTF8.txt');
    if List.Encoding = TEncoding.Unicode then
      EncName := 'Unicode'
    else if List.Encoding = TEncoding.UTF8 then
      EncName := 'UTF8'
    else
      EncName := 'Default';

    Memo1.Lines.Assign(List);
    Memo1.Lines.Add;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Encoding : ' + EncName);
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: many thanks for your fine answer, and for editing my post :-) When I read it again along with your answer I didn't remember that I wrote a so good English !